# Problem with first login to activiti cloud

Tags: http-status-code-403, activiti, bpmn

I would like to prepare an environment to work with Activiti. I followed the instruction posted on https://activiti.gitbook.io/activiti-7-developers-guide/getting-started/getting-started-activiti-cloud/getting-started-docker-compose. I'm stuck at the point of launching the application. I typed `make modeler` in cmd and then I opened *127.0.0.1/modeling* and I try to login. I fill the username field like "admin" and password field also as "admin". [Here is screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EuXY.png). And then I
received 403 error  [like on the photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MK6hd.png).

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try to use the following login credentials:**

login: modeler

password: password